# how to fetch particular fields within a metrics from elastic search in go

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I have inserted the below value into the elastic search with index name:count

```
{
"Id": "12345",
"Count": 
{
    "Timestamp": "2019-02-21T17:21:45.257013Z", 
    "TotalInstances": 300,  
    "RunningInstances": 80
}
```

}

i need to fetch the value of time stamp ,total instance and running instance based on id.
I am using
https://olivere.github.io/elastic/

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: i am facing issue when i am trying to get the data within "Count"